# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date “yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX” - SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I used the follow code to parse `datetime`:

```
String parseDate(String tranDateTime, String originalDateFormat, String toDateFormat) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat originalMonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat(originalDateFormat);
    Date date = originalMonthYear.parse(tranDateTime);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(toDateFormat);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

And tried to parse a datetime value as below :

```
parseDate("2017-08-16T00:00:00Z", 
          "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

An exception is thrown :

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-08-16T00:00:00Z"

However, when I change date value to `"2017-08-16T02:54:15.537Z"`, the function worked fine. I don't know why.

Comment: "I don't know why?" Because you told your program to do so. The pattern includes `.SSS` for a milliseconds part.

Comment: `2017-08-16T02:54:15.537Z` works because you use a right seconds part format SS.SSS.

Comment: Lesson learnt from your answers. Appreciate your time

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` are long outdated and the former in particular notoriously troublesome. I advise you not to use them and use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. As a bonus, `OffsetDateTime.parse(String)` will parse both of your example strings without any explicit formatter.

Comment: `Instant.parse( "2017-08-16T00:00:00Z" )`  works just fine, as [you can see in IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wyd9Sw). Time to abandon those terrible old legacy classes `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`. Now supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6):

The problem is coming from :

```
Date date = originalMonthYear.parse(tranDateTime);
```

This date

```
2017-08-16T00:00:00Z
```

Doesn't match the pattern

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

Because milliseconds are missing (`SSS` part)

So

```
Date date = originalMonthYear.parse(tranDateTime);
```

Throws the exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-08-16T00:00:00Z"
```

**Solutions**

- Change your date `2017-08-16T00:00:00Z` into `2017-08-16T00:00:00.000Z` (add milliseconds to your date)
- Change your pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` into `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` (remove milliseconds from your pattern)

Comment: Moreover, the datetime  value could be "2017-08-16T00:00:00Z" or "2017-08-16T00:00:15.537Z" retrieved from database. Do we have a general pattern to parse both formats? If no, I have to use if condition to parse for each format

Comment: @PeterT you can easily check the length of the `String` to parse to know which pattern to use.

Comment: I recommend you to stick to only one pattern. International Organization for Standardization (ISO) for representation of date and time is [ISO_8601](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), it defines to use this DateTime pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` (ie : `2018-02-20T18:50:31Z`)

Comment: @PeterT, you can use the thrown exception in the right way to use many format patterns, take a look on my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

You asked in a comment:

> Moreover, the datetime value could be "2017-08-16T00:00:00Z" or
>   "2017-08-16T00:00:15.537Z" retrieved from database. Do we have a
>   general pattern to parse both formats?

Even better, they can both be parsed *without* an explicit pattern:

```
    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-08-16T00:00:00Z"));
    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-08-16T00:00:15.537Z"));
```

This prints:

```
2017-08-16T00:00Z
2017-08-16T00:00:15.537Z
```

To format, for example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-08-16T00:00:00Z").format(formatter));
```

This prints

```
2017-08-16 00:00:00
```

I am using and warmly recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` are long outmoded and the former in particular notoriously troublesome. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

Your strings (in spite of differences) both conform to ISO 8601, the standard for date and time formats. The `java.time` classes parse these formats without any explicit formatter.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`

Answer (score 1):

Change `2017-08-16T00:00:00Z` to `2017-08-16T00:00:00.000Z`, it works for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer.
You are setting your timeformat up with `SSSXXX` so you are expecting a measurement of milliseconds and a timezone. You use Z for the timezone but no measurement in milliseconds so your parser can not parse it.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem source :**

The problem come from trying to pars date value `2017-08-16T00:00:00Z` with a date format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`, in the line :

```
Date date = originalMonthYear.parse(tranDateTime);
```

See the difference between the value and format:

```
 ______________________________
|2017|08|16| T |00|00|00Z      |
|yyyy|MM|dd|'T'|HH|mm|ss.SSSXXX|
|____|__|__|___|__|__|_________|
```

**Solution** :

Simple one is :

```
Date date = originalMonthYear.parse("2017-08-16T00:00:00.000Z")
```

But, if you will get many differents formats, you can use something like (**never tested**):

```
List<SimpleDateFormat> myUsedPatterns = new ArrayList<>();

myUsedPatterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"));
myUsedPatterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));

for (SimpleDateFormat myPattern : myUsedPatterns) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat originalMonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat(myPattern );
        Date date = originalMonthYear.parse(tranDateTime);

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(toDateFormat);
        return formatter.format(date);
        
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted the answer, would you care to write a comment on why, please? For us all to learn.